# Embed the Crosswalk runtime into a Cordova application

Tags: cordova, webview, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I'm using **Cordova 4 & Cordova CLI 5.3.1** + Crosswalk (cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.3.1)

I want to build an hybrid application (ios/android) that loads a webpage with a game that use WebGL.

Without Crosswalk webview the game works great on Android 5, iOS 8, but on Android 4.4 the performance is not so good.

So I have tried using the webview from Crosswalk and it works great, the only problem I have is that they use a separate application (Crosswalk Project Runtime)

So I have followed their tutorial to embed the runtime into the app. I'm doing exactly what they say on this page:

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html

**Maybe they have a compatibility problem with Cordoba >= 5 ?**

When I open the application this error is displayed, the only way to continue is installing the Crosswalk project from the Google Play Store:

[image]

But the runtime is embedded because the apk size is: 20MB without any other asset than a html file.

The `config.xml` file content is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="example" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Example</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="14+" />
    <preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
    <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
</widget>
```

**I'm not doing anything different from their example and is not working, anyone knows what can be?**

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you solve problem?

Answer (score 1):

Very strange, everything works fine on my side, and the size of apk is 25.1 MB.
Just share you my steps:

    `$ cordova -v
    5.3.1
    $ cordova create Example
    $ cd Example & cordova platform add android
    $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
    $ cordova build android`

And I am curious why your id in the config.xml is only consist of one word, as usual it should be like `xxx.xxx.xxx`, e.g. `com.example.foo`

Answer (score 0):

crosswalk plugin generates two types of apk (arm and x86), you must use the correct package for the architecture of your system.
"google play" you can put the two packages and installation will use the correct apk.

Comment: It`s wrong, cause if we have combined build for each platform it must work on device with different platforms.